# 'No Related list to Display' error in Salesforce lightning Expr for only one User

Tags: lightning, sales, user-profile

We have a User who can not see related list of the Opportunity (Classic and Lightning both) though he owns few records if not then he is there as Sales team member in Opportunity. He is getting an error message as '**No Related list to Display**'. 
Opportunity is Private in OWD. We don't have any permission sets. Now the main twist is - Other users having the same Profile have no issues and they can see the related list. Amazed what is missing for that User as the Users with the same role & profile does not have any issue. 
If anyone has any clue please let me know. 
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, this user is unable to see the related lists for *objects related to Opportunity*? What are the related objects and their own sharing settings?

Comment: Oportunity --> Private, Finance_Info (Custom Object) --> Private . All Other Users with the same profile can see this and other Opportunities without any issue ( there is permission set).  Even this guy  is in Sales team as member he is getting this error.

Comment: You said in your question that you do *not* have permission sets. Opportunity Team Member status would not override Field-Level Security on the child object if the user is missing permissions.

Comment: Thanks David Reed for your quick response. Other Users with the Same profile are fine. Any particular area we can focus more regarding this?